# Parse Error: Expected no additional symbols at symbol

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

```
username =  self.request.get('username')
groupName =  db.GqlQuery("SELECT group FROM Person WHERE name = :1", username).get()
```

I'm getting error "Parse Error: Expected no additional symbols at symbol group". What is wrong?

---

```
objPerson = Person.get_by_key_name(username) # load
self.response.out.write(str(objPerson))
```

It returns "None"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GQL != SQL
You can't select a specific field in GQL (other than `__key__`)

```
person =  self.request.get('username') groupName = 
  db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE name = :1", username).get()
group_name = person.group
```

Also you might want to consider using the buitin key_name to store and retrieve Person entities instead of query for them.

```
Person(key_name = username) # store
Person.get_by_key_name(username) # load
```

Comment: When I'm trying to get groupName as a string - db.Gql Query returns link to an object. How to get it as a string?